# className attribute on button is not working - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's a cart, I am displaying the total amount of the items added to the cart. I have added different styles to the elements, and everything works fine. But the style on both the buttons won't change.

[image: Current output]
[image: Expected output]

Cart.js:

```
import Modal from "../UI/Modal";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";

const Cart = (props) => {
  const cardItems = (
    <ul className={classes['cart-items']}>
      {[{ id: "c1", name: "Sushi", amount: 2, price: 12.99 }].map((item) => (
        <li>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  return (
    <Modal>
      {cardItems}
      <div className={classes.total}>
          <span>Total Amount</span>
          <span>35.62</span>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.action}>
          <button className={classes['button--alt']}>Close</button>
          <button className={classes.button}>Order</button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Cart.module.css:

```
   
  .actions button {
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #8a2b06;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
  
  .actions button:hover,
  .actions button:active {
    background-color: #5a1a01;
    border-color: #5a1a01;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .actions .button--alt {
    color: #8a2b06;
  }
  
  .actions .button {
    background-color: #8a2b06;
    color: white;
  }
```

Comment: In your component should'nt it be `classes.actions` instead if `classes.action`?

Comment: Yup, my bad Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change *classes.action* to *classes.actions*

```
import Modal from "../UI/Modal";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";

const Cart = (props) => {
  const cardItems = (
    <ul className={classes['cart-items']}>
      {[{ id: "c1", name: "Sushi", amount: 2, price: 12.99 }].map((item) => (
        <li>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  return (
    <Modal>
      {cardItems}
      <div className={classes.total}>
          <span>Total Amount</span>
          <span>35.62</span>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button className={classes['button--alt']}>Close</button>
          <button className={classes.button}>Order</button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo in your `className` in

```jsx
<div className={classes.actions}>
```

`<div className={classes.actions}>` instead of `<div className={classes.action}>`

It's working if it is `classes.actions`.

[image]

Comment: My bad didn't see that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found your bug

```
  <div className={classes.action}>
      <button className={classes['button--alt']}>Close</button>
      <button className={classes.button}>Order</button>
  </div>
```

You're using classes.action but in the css its actions (without s)

**solution:**

```
   <div className={classes.actions}>
```

change action to actions.